# Trying to implement an android spinner. but when I touch it, the dropdown menu doesn't open. nothing happens. why?

Tags: android, spinner

I was trying to implement an android spinner, a button, if I click should open a dropdown menu showing three things: "bluetooth, speak, headphones"
but all i see now is the button, (no text), and when I click on it, nothing happens. what am i missing?

here is my code:
in the xml i have:

> ```
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:id="@+id/audio_routing"
>         android:layout_width="40dp"
>         android:layout_height="40dp"
>         android:padding="10dp" >
>         <Spinner
>             android:id="@+id/audio_routing_spinner"
>             android:layout_width="20dp"
>             android:layout_height="40dp"
>             android:contentDescription="@string/audio_routing_desc"
>             android:scaleType="fitXY"
>             android:src="@drawable/bluetooth" />
>     </RelativeLayout>
> ```

in the strings file i have:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
> ...
> <string name="audio_routing_desc">Audio Routing Button</string>
> <!-- Audio Routing Drop Down List -->
> <string-array name="audio_routing_array">
>     <item>Bluetooth</item>
>     <item>Headphones</item>
>     <item>Speaker</item>
> </string-array>
> ```

in my java file i have:

> ```
>   void audio_routing() {
>     kcLogger.info("audio_routing", "audio_routing function is called");
>     Spinner spinner = (Spinner) mKCSWindowView.findViewById(R.id.audio_routing_spinner); 
>
>   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(service,R.array.audio_routing_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
>
>     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
>     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
>     spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>             kcLogger.info("audio_routing", "onItemSelected");
>         }
>         @Override
>         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>             kcLogger.info("audio_routing", "onNothingSelected");
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

Comment: I think it should be android:entries and not android:contentDescription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change android:contentDescription to android:entries

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/audio_routing_spinner"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:entries="@array/audio_routing_desc"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bluetooth" />
```

**[android:contentDescription](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:contentDescription)** is for accessibility features.
**android:entries** is used to set array data to UI like spinner, listview, gridview,etc.

Comment: do you mean,
>         android:entries="@string/audio_routing_array"
?
if so, it doesnot recognize my array for some odd reason,Error: "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'entries' with value '@string/audio_routing_array)

Comment: because in my strings file i have this:
<string name="audio_routing_desc">Audio Routing Button</string>

Comment: oh nvm, it should be android:entries="@array/audio_routing_array"

Comment: now it is fixed, the dropdown menu shows up when i touch/click the spinner. now I want the spinner thing to have a picture on it, no text. 
i already have android:src"@drawable/blutooth" but obviously that isn't working, I dont see any picture.
any ideas?

Comment: oh, i wrote: android:background"@drawable/bluetooth" and the image appeared. now the problem is, the drop down menu only open the first time i click it. the second time i touch the spinner the downdown disappears (like it is supposed to).. but the 3rd time when i touch it again, the dropdown doesn't open. now i need to figure how to fix this.